# Basic Username/Password Code not working in C - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, cs50

I've just started learning C 2 days ago and have tried to write a code that prompts the user to submit a username and password and then cross-references the input with stored data. The idea is that if the inputted username and password match then "Access Granted" would be printed and if not, "Access Denied".

However, I keep receiving "Access Denied.Segmentation fault" whenever I test the code with inputs. Any thoughts on why this would happen? Attaching my code below for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int N;

typedef struct
{
    string Username;
    string Password;
}
LoginInfo;

int main(void)
{
    LoginInfo code[N];

    code[0].Username = "Agent X";
    code[0].Password = "1314XN";

    code[1].Username = "Agent Y";
    code[1].Password = "1315YN";

    code[2].Username = "Agent Z";
    code[2].Password = "1316ZN";

    code[3].Username = "Director A";
    code[3].Password = "1414AN";

    code[4].Username = "VP A";
    code[4].Password = "1628VPN";

    string User = get_string("Username: ");
    string Pass = get_string("Password: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if((strcmp(code[i].Username, User) == 0) && (strcmp(code[i].Password, Pass) == 0))
        {
            printf("Access Granted.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Access Denied.");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `N` is 0. You probably meant for it to be something else.

Comment: Can you show us `cs50.h`, or some documentation for that? the `string` type is not provided by `string.h` in C, and wouldn't work like this in C++ either.

Comment: C without `string` keyword. define a string, just use `char *`, and then explicitly malloc merroy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The `cs50.h` header defines `string` as `char*`.  It's a terrible idea and only leads to confusion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In cs50 string is a char*. https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h

Comment: Ah, so this is some well-known (if pedagogic) third-party library? From the name I assumed it was specific to a particular course at a particular university.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's from [Harvard's CS50 course](https://cs50.harvard.edu), but I think it's also used elsewhere.

Comment: @Aziz never use `string` as it is not a standard type in C (and it hides the fact that you're working with a pointer), always use `char*` instead, which ist the correct type for strings in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `int N;` but didn't initialize it. Since it's at global scope it's given a value of 0.

When you reach the line `LoginInfo code[N];` the value of `N` is still 0 so the array is given a size of 0. Accessing any elements of the array leads to undefined behavior and is the likely source of the fault.

You need to initialize `N` or otherwise give it a reasonable value before it's used. For example:

```
int N = 5; // Initialize this!
```

With this change your code compiles cleanly and runs. [Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/RjA_zF)

Answer (score -2):

You aren't defining a value for N so if you want N to be 5 change this to

```
#define N 5
```

Without a value for N, it is 0 (likely), and so the array is of size 0 and you will always get a segmentation fault.

Comment: We don't need people to go with preprocessor defines. Constexpr would do.

Comment: He has it hard coded for 5 values, that would work just fine. He isn't dynamically changing the value anywhere.

Comment: He is also just learning C, so probably having an easy define is easier than some of the other suggestions with malloc and such. Just trying to provide an easy explanation for someone who doesn't know much about the language.

Comment: `constexpr` is not any harder to use than the preprocessor, and is a much better habit.

Comment: It is a preference. #defines are used to define sizes and other numbers often in the field still. You may not like the style but it is still a valid answer and addresses why he is getting the seg fault.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hope you got your code working. You can def use a const int as an alternative. In school and in practice, I've seen both used. And the basics of the answer is that N wasn't defined.   If you see seg fault, it usually means that you don't have access to that memory for some reason (like went past the length of an array or are de-referencing a null pointer).